# Throttle API calls to external service using Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, akka-stream

I have a service exposing a REST endpoint that, after a couple of transformations, calls a third-party service also via its REST endpoint.

I would like to implement some sort of throttling on my service to avoid being throttled by this third-party service. Note that my service's endpoint accepts only one request and not a list of them. I'm using Play and we also have Akka Streams as dependency.

My first though was to have my service saving the requests into a database table and then have an Akka Streams `Source`, leveraging the `throttle` function, picking tasks, applying the transformations and then calling the external service.

Is this a reasanoble approach or does it have any severe drawbacks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why save the requests to the database? Does the queue need to survive restarts and/or do you run a load-balanced setup that needs to somehow synchronize the requests?

If you don't need the above I'd think using only `Source.queue` to store the task data would work just as well?

And maybe you already thought of this: If you want to make your endpoint more resilient you should allow your API to send a 'sorry, busy' response and drop the request instead of queuing it if your queue grows beyond a certain size.

Comment: As you pointed out, I don't really need the db. I've already thought of `Source.queue`, but from [this example](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/operators/Source/queue.html) I can't figure out how my Controller would tell it's Service to enqueue a new element to be processed.